# It shows syntax error about missing enclosing tag while I've added enclosing tag

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I am using a react-native-gifted-chat example which doesn't have a header. I've tried to add header from native-base. After integration, it says error about missing enclosing tag while it was already there. How can this fixed? Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title, Text } from 'native-base';

import {GiftedChat, Actions, Bubble, SystemMessage} from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import CustomActions from './CustomActions';
import CustomView from './CustomView';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
      loadEarlier: true,
      typingText: null,
      isLoadingEarlier: false,
    };

    this._isMounted = false;
    this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this);
    this.onReceive = this.onReceive.bind(this);
    this.renderCustomActions = this.renderCustomActions.bind(this);
    this.renderBubble = this.renderBubble.bind(this);
    this.renderSystemMessage = this.renderSystemMessage.bind(this);
    this.renderFooter = this.renderFooter.bind(this);
    this.onLoadEarlier = this.onLoadEarlier.bind(this);

    this._isAlright = null;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        messages: require('./data/messages.js'),
      };
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  onLoadEarlier() {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        isLoadingEarlier: true,
      };
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this._isMounted === true) {
        this.setState((previousState) => {
          return {
            messages: GiftedChat.prepend(previousState.messages, require('./data/old_messages.js')),
            loadEarlier: false,
            isLoadingEarlier: false,
          };
        });
      }
    }, 1000); // simulating network
  }

  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
      };
    });

    // for demo purpose
    this.answerDemo(messages);
  }

  answerDemo(messages) {
    if (messages.length > 0) {
      if ((messages[0].image || messages[0].location) || !this._isAlright) {
        this.setState((previousState) => {
          return {
            typingText: 'React Native is typing'
          };
        });
      }
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this._isMounted === true) {
        if (messages.length > 0) {
          if (messages[0].image) {
            this.onReceive('Nice picture!');
          } else if (messages[0].location) {
            this.onReceive('My favorite place');
          } else {
            if (!this._isAlright) {
              this._isAlright = true;
              this.onReceive('Alright');
            }
          }
        }
      }

      this.setState((previousState) => {
        return {
          typingText: null,
        };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  onReceive(text) {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, {
          _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
          text: text,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            // avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        }),
      };
    });
  }

  renderCustomActions(props) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      return (
        <CustomActions
          {...props}
        />
      );
    }
    const options = {
      'Action 1': (props) => {
        alert('option 1');
      },
      'Action 2': (props) => {
        alert('option 2');
      },
      'Cancel': () => {},
    };
    return (
      <Actions
        {...props}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }

  renderBubble(props) {
    return (
      <Bubble
        {...props}
        wrapperStyle={{
          left: {
            backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  renderSystemMessage(props) {
    return (
      <SystemMessage
        {...props}
        containerStyle={{
          marginBottom: 15,
        }}
        textStyle={{
          fontSize: 14,
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  renderCustomView(props) {
    return (
      <CustomView
        {...props}
      />
    );
  }

  renderFooter(props) {
    if (this.state.typingText) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.footerText}>
            {this.state.typingText}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
 <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='arrow-back' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Header</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Button transparent>
              <Text>Cancel</Text>
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={this.onSend}
        loadEarlier={this.state.loadEarlier}
        onLoadEarlier={this.onLoadEarlier}
        isLoadingEarlier={this.state.isLoadingEarlier}

        user={{
          _id: 1, // sent messages should have same user._id
        }}

        renderActions={this.renderCustomActions}
        renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
        renderSystemMessage={this.renderSystemMessage}
        renderCustomView={this.renderCustomView}
        renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footerContainer: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  footerText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#aaa',
  },
});
```

It shows syntax error about the missing enclosing tag on this line

```
 <GiftedChat
            messages={this.state.messages}
            onSend={this.onSend}
            loadEarlier={this.state.loadEarlier}
            onLoadEarlier={this.onLoadEarlier}
            isLoadingEarlier={this.state.isLoadingEarlier}

            user={{
              _id: 1, // sent messages should have same user._id
            }}

            renderActions={this.renderCustomActions}
            renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
            renderSystemMessage={this.renderSystemMessage}
            renderCustomView={this.renderCustomView}
            renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
          />
```

Most interesting part is that before adding a native base header in the above giftedchat component it wasn't shown such error while after integration it said that strange error. What can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a single element/component that has child elements/components. You are trying to return 2 sibling component. Wrap them with a View or a similar component and then return.

**Example**

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon name='arrow-back' />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>Header</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <Button transparent>
            <Text>Cancel</Text>
          </Button>
        </Right>
      </Header>
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={this.onSend}
        loadEarlier={this.state.loadEarlier}
        onLoadEarlier={this.onLoadEarlier}
        isLoadingEarlier={this.state.isLoadingEarlier}
        user={{
          _id: 1, // sent messages should have same user._id
        }}
        renderActions={this.renderCustomActions}
        renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
        renderSystemMessage={this.renderSystemMessage}
        renderCustomView={this.renderCustomView}
        renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried it but chat was disappeared. Just header left. :(